# Angular Circular Dependency. Service -> State -> Service. How to deal with this?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, architecture, rxjs, ngxs

**UPDATE: (updates comes at the top)**

As I am using NGXS, I've remade my service/state using the next approach:
In the class, that was calling the service - the service is no longer called. Instead, it dispatched an action. So the state launches the appropriate reducer for that action and calls the service method renewAccessToken, padding the refreshToken as a parameter.
This is good way I've done.

But... I've still a problem (a totally another problem).
The class which dispatches an action actually is a custom HTTP_INTERCEPTOR, and I want to make a request.clone(), if the token was refreshed successfully.

I am thinking on the resolutions... Advices are welcome.

**INITIAL QUESTION:**

I understand the error.
But I am here to ask you for advices, how to deal with that.
How should I change my structure, using best practices?

I am using Ionic + Angular + NGXS.

My current idea is to take the refreshToken directly from the `localStorage`, without injecting `AuthState` in the `AuthService`. But I think that this is not a best way to deal with such problems.

My current code is attached below:

**State**:

```
import { State, Action, StateContext, Selector, Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ImmutableContext } from '@ngxs-labs/immer-adapter';
import { AuthModel } from './model';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import {
  TryLogin,
  LoginFailed,
  LoginSucceess,
  TryLogout,
  LogoutSuccess
} from 'src/app/pages/login/store/actions';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UiService } from 'src/app/services/ui.service';
import { Unauthorized } from 'src/app/errors/response-errors/unauthorized';

@State<AuthModel>({
  name: 'auth',
  defaults: {
    token: null,
    refreshToken: null
  }
})
@Injectable()
export class AuthState {
  @Selector()
  static token(state: AuthModel): string | null {
    return state.token;
  }

  @Selector()
  static refreshToken(state: AuthModel): string | null {
    return state.refreshToken;
  }

  @Selector()
  static isAuthenticated(state: AuthModel): boolean {
    if (state.token) {
      const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();

      if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(state.token)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private store: Store,
    private uiService: UiService
  ) {}

  @Action(TryLogin)
  @ImmutableContext()
  login({ setState }: StateContext<AuthModel>, { payload }: TryLogin) {
    this.uiService.displayLoading();
    return this.authService.login(payload).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        this.uiService.dismissLoading();
        if (err instanceof Unauthorized) {
          this.store.dispatch(new LoginFailed());
        }
        return of(null);
      }),
      tap((result: any) => {
        this.uiService.dismissLoading();
        if (result) {
          setState((state: AuthModel) => {
            state.token = result.token;
            state.refreshToken = result.refresh_token;

            return state;
          });
          this.store.dispatch(new LoginSucceess());
        }
      })
    );
  }

  @Action(TryLogout)
  @ImmutableContext()
  logout({ setState }: StateContext<AuthModel>, {}: TryLogout) {
    setState((state: AuthModel) => {
      state.token = null;
      state.refreshToken = null;

      return state;
    });
    this.store.dispatch(new LogoutSuccess());
  }
}
```

**Service**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginForm } from '../pages/login/interfaces/login-form';
import { AuthState } from '../store/auth/state';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService extends ApiService {
  refreshToken$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }

  login(credentials: LoginForm) {
    console.log('AuthService:login');
    return this.post('/login', {
      email: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password
    });
  }

  renewAccessToken(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('AuthService:renewAccessToken');
    return this.post('/renew-access-token', {
      refresh_token: AuthState.refreshToken
    });
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
[ng] WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
[ng] src/app/services/auth.service.ts -> src/app/store/auth/state.ts -> src/app/services/auth.service.ts
```

Comment: just move refresh token and token to be stored in service, that makes more sense.

Comment: have you ever used NGXS?

Comment: yes, i am using it in the project, but i also use singleton service to store temporary data. I don't create instance property in state

Comment: refreshToken is not a temporary data. It lives in auth state for a long time, which saves it in the localStorage under the hood

Comment: if you really want to save in state, why not create another action in the state to for saving token and when auth service fetched the token you can dispatch the action within the state action function, then you should be able to avoid circular dependency.

Comment: read the updated text :)

Comment: i find interceptor quite intrusive to use,  i normally create my own http wrapper and put extra handling there. customHttp.service for example.